# Retrofit 2.5.0 not executing request after third time

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have the following code,

```java
@Singleton
class LoginHandler {
    private Observable<Response<User>> loginObservable;

    private void attemptLogin(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        LoginSubscriber loginSubscriber = new LoginSubscriber();

        loginObservable = api.login(loginRequest);
        loginObservable
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe(loginSubscriber);
    }
}
```

with

```java
@POST(PATH_AUTH)
Observable<Response<User>> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
```

This gets executed each time the user wants to login from a deep link.

I can log in and log out two times, but on the third time, the request just does not get executed. I also checked with the Charles Proxy tool, if the request is actually sent, but there was nothing to see.
Logging the `loginObservable` object shows that each `api.login()` call returns a different Observable object, which is correct for the subscription to be executed. Logging at `doOnSubscribe(() -> ...)` is also executed, just not the request itself.
I've browsed through SO and the only solution I found was to add a `timeout(...)` so that the user is able to get back to the login mask, once the timeout strikes. However when retrying to log in, the problem is still present.

**So my question is, how could I debug this and find out, what is happening under the hood of retrofit and why is the request not executed after the third attempt?**

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I would have thought this line : `loginObservable = api.login(loginRequest);` should be `loginObservable = Observable.defer(() -> api.login(loginRequest));` - why are you assigning it to a variable anyway (if you subscribe to `loginObservable` elsewhere it will unsubscribe any current subscriptions)? Have you written any unit tests and if so do they yield the same result?  Might be worth showing the retrofit/okhttp module as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought retrofit takes care of the actual execution of the request once `subscribe` is called. Therefore `defer(() -> ...)` is not needed. And yes, the observable is used elsewhere; also it is a good point you mentioned, that subscribing it elsewhere unsubscribes any other subscriptions.
However, for some remote reason, the problem does not appear anymore. I guess I'll just have to leave this for now. Cheers.

Comment: @markkeen not really. The library rxretrofit provides calladapters for observables. And this is what I am currently using. With the help of the library, the requests are only fired, when the `subscribe()` method is called.